# Scatter-plot using markers in heaply?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scatter-plot, healpy

I am recently using healpy. I made the following scattered plot using 'projplot' and I have used markersize to define the size. Here is the plot:
[here the size of the circles are arrording tothe value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgKpW.png)

Now I want to make the same figure with the colorbar according to the value. I want something like the following in galactic plane: [Here the colorbar shows the values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT4SC.png)

I think I need to use 'markercolor' but I am not sure. Can you please tell me the code how to produce the scattered plot with colorbar(like in 2nd figure: every circle should get color according to the value )?
Thank you in advance.